# how to open a new widget by using mousepressEvent

Tags: python, pyqt4, mayavi

here i am tacking x,y position by using mouse press event when i click any position i want to open a new widget?in that widget i want to create a 3d plot,can you pls help me how to do this problem 
given bellow is my code:

```
 def mousePressEvent(self, evnt):
            print evnt
            print dir(evnt)
            print evnt.screenPos().x()
            print evnt.screenPos().y()


            self.ix = int(evnt.screenPos().x()/Setting.WIDTH)
            self.iy = int(evnt.screenPos().y()/Setting.HEIGHT)
            print self.ix , self.iy
            #self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()
            #self.widget.show()


import scipy as np
from mayavi import mlab


x,y = np.mgrid[-3:3:100j, -3:3:100j]

a = 0.3

a0 = 0.2

r1=np.sqrt((x-a)**2 + y**2)

values = np.sinc(-r1/a0)



mlab.surf(values, warp_scale='auto')

mlab.outline()

mlab.axes()
# mlab.test_contour3d()
mlab.show()
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: when i click any position of x,y it will open  a new widget in that widget i want to create a 3d plot,here i don't know how to interconnected with mousepressEvent to widget in that 3d plot

Comment: Do you only want the Mayavi window to open ?, what does the coordinates of the x, and the PyQt widget have to do with the window generated by mayavi ?, I do not understand you, explain yourself.

Comment: I just do not understand what your problem is, I see a commented code that opens a window, what's your problem?

Comment: when i clicked the any position of x,y by using mousepressevent, i want to open a mayavi window

Comment: okay, I understand you but in your code you give a lot of emphasis to the position of the mouse because as you point out is irrelavante, you want something like: `class Widget(QWidget):` `def mousePressEvent (self, event): foo_call_window()`

Comment: can you pls tell me clearly otherwise send me  any reference example  link because  two days back only i started this course

Comment: I am working on it, but never signs that these days working, for us it is irrelevant, it does not generate pressure. For example it revises: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_qt_embedding.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QApplication

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def mousePressEvent(self, evnt):
        print evnt
        print dir(evnt)
        print evnt.screenPos().x()
        print evnt.screenPos().y()


        self.ix = int(evnt.screenPos().x()/Setting.WIDTH)
        self.iy = int(evnt.screenPos().y()/Setting.HEIGHT)
        print self.ix , self.iy
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = MyWidget()
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: i am beginner in pyqt4 can you pls say how to add this widget ex:widget = QtGui.MyWidget() or normally

Comment: You have to have PyQt package installed. Then you import QtGui from it

Comment: thankyou so much ..in this wedget i want draw a 3d plot  in between can i write my code

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316781/drawing-a-polygon-in-pyqt

Comment: @Azazel change `widget = MyWidget` to `widget = MyWidget()`